# AmCharts with multiple dataset and different baloon appearance

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using AmCharts to display temperature indications. This data has multiple lines, so I load multiple dataSets in chart. Also I need to display pill giving times. This dataSet must show different text in baloon text. Also I have another problem: only first dataSet is shown in category scroll bar.

How can I do it?

[My code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/s7ghcyzn/)

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  // check if plugin is enabled
  if (chart.syncDataTimestamps !== true)
    return;

  // go thorugh all data sets and collect all the different timestamps
  var dates = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataSets.length; i++) {
    var ds = chart.dataSets[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < ds.dataProvider.length; x++) {
      var date = ds.dataProvider[x][ds.categoryField];
      if (dates[date.getTime()] === undefined)
        dates[date.getTime()] = {};
      dates[date.getTime()][i] = ds.dataProvider[x];
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataSets.length; i++) {
    var ds = chart.dataSets[i];
    var dp = [];
    for (var ts in dates) {
      if (!dates.hasOwnProperty(ts))
        continue;
      var row = dates[ts];
      if (row[i] === undefined) {
        row[i] = {};
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(ts);
        row[i][ds.categoryField] = d;
      }
      dp.push(row[i]);
    }
    dp.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(a[ds.categoryField]) - new Date(b[ds.categoryField]);
    });
    ds.dataProvider = dp;
  }

}, ["stock"]);
var chartData1 = [{  
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 10
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 11
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 12
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 11
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 11
}, ];

var chartData2 = [{
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 1
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 2
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 3
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 10
}, {
  date: new Date(2011, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  value: 4
}, ];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        //*
        "type": "stock",
        "theme": "light",
        "syncDataTimestamps": true,
        "language": "ru",

        dataSets: [
          {
            title: "temperature1",
            fieldMappings: [
              {
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value"
              }
            ],
            compared: true,
            dataProvider: chartData1,
            categoryField: "date"
          },
          {
            title: "temperature1",
            fieldMappings: [
              {
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value"
              }
            ],
            compared: true,
            dataProvider: chartData2,
            categoryField: "date"
          }
        ],

        "categoryAxesSettings": {
            "position": "bottom",
            "parseDates": false,
            "dashLength": 1,
            "minorGridEnabled": false,
            "equalSpacing": false,
            "minPeriod": "ss",
            "gridColor": "fff",
            "position": "top",
            "axisColor": "#f591b3"
        },
        "chartScrollbarSettings": {
            "graph": "g1",
            "position": "bottom",
            "oppositeAxis": false,
            "backgroundAlpha": 0,
            "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.4,
            "selectedBackgroundColor": "#F592B3",
            "graphFillAlpha": 0,
            "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
            "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
            "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
            "color": "#AAAAAA"
        },
        panels: [{
            recalculateToPercents: 'never',

            stockGraphs: [{
                id: "g1",
                valueField: "value",
                comparable: true,
                compareField: "value",
                compareGraphBullet: 'round',
                compareGraphBulletSize: 3,
                "lineColor": "#F591B3",
                compareGraph: {
                    "color": "#F592B3",
                    "baloonColor": "#F591B3",
                    baloon: {
                        "adjustBorderColor": true,
                        "color": "#fff",
                        "cornerRadius": 5,
                        "fillColor": "#F591B3",
                        "fillAlpha": 1,
                        "borderAlpha": 0,
                        "shadowAlpha": 0,
                        "fontSize": 10,
                    },
                    baloonText: "[[value]]"
                },
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmCharts only supports one graph object inside the scrollbar, which means only the first `dataSet` is drawn. There is no workaround for this outside of removing the graph from the scrollbar if you don't want it to look different from the chart.

As for the balloons, the relevant properties are called [*`balloon`*](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmBalloon) and [*`balloonText`*](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#balloonText) - you misspelled `balloon` as `baloon` in both cases. Set the desired properties in [`compareGraph`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#compareGraph) and you're set. You also don't need to set `compared: true` in the first `dataSet` object as it will duplicate the balloon in the compared graph.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7ghcyzn/1/)